# How can I fire another event from a Timer.Elapsed event?

Tags: c#, timer, sqlcommand

I have a timer, which polls every 5 seconds for new SMS Messages received by a GSM Modem, the code for getting the messages works fine, however I want to continuously check for new messages every 5 seconds.

My problem is that when I attempt to fire the event which goes away and collects these messages, from my Timer.Elapsed event, I get 9 errors, I have called the event handler like you do any other method and attempted to pass the appropriate arguments in, but for some reason it will not compile!

Code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated =]

When this is working I do intend to parameterize the SqlCommand!!!

for the timer

```
 public void Pollback()
   {
       Timer poller = new Timer(5000);
       poller.Enabled = true;
       poller.Start();
       if (poller.Interval==0)
       {
           GsmPhone_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e);
       }
   }
```

for my event handler which handles incoming messages from the Modem

```
public void GsmPhone_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Log("Message Received");

            //var message = GSM.ReadMessage(4);
            //GSM.ReadMessage(4);
            //TcpClientChannel client = new TcpClientChannel();
            //ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(client, false);
            //string url = "192.168.100.67:2000";
            //ISmsSender smssender = (ISmsSender)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ISmsSender), url);

            try
            {

                SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*********,****;Initial Catalog=******;User ID=********;Password=*******");
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                com.Connection = Conn;
                Conn.Open();
                com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO My_Table(ID,Message,Blacklist) VALUES(2,'"+GSM.ReadMessage(4).ToString()+"', 'Yes')");
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Conn.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var exception = ex.ToString();
                Log(exception);

            }
```

Comment: Extract code from event handler to separate method, and call this method both from GsmPhone_MessageReceived handler and Pollback

Comment: Of course! I should've known that really, thanks for your help guys; you've been so helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to break the logic out of the other event into a separate method, then call that method wherever you need it.

I modified your SQL query to use parameters (more secure, easier to maintain), and added some `using` blocks so you automagically close / dispose the connection when you no longer need it.

Also, I'm not sure how `if (poller.Interval) == 0` could ever be `true`, since you're setting the interval to 5000 ms when you instantiate the `Timer` class. If you mean to call that block of code when the interval elapses, you can call it from the `Elapsed` event.

```
public void Pollback()
{
    Timer poller = new Timer(5000);
    poller.Elapsed += (s, e) => InsertMessage();
    poller.Start();  // "Start()" sets "Enabled = true", so you don't need the other statement
}

public void GsmPhone_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    InsertMessage();
}

private void InsertMessage()
{
    Log("Message Received");

    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*********,****;Initial Catalog=******;User ID=********;Password=*******"))
        {
            using (var com = new SqlCommand())
            {
                com.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO My_Table(ID,Message,Blacklist) VALUES(2, @Message, 'Yes')");
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", GSM.ReadMessage(4).ToString());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Grant, thanks very much! one last thing before I mark as answered, could I simply call InsertMessage on the Elapsed event rather than using the If Statement as above?

Answer (score 0):

The argument for the Timer constructor is the interval. Since you are passing in 5000, your if statement will never be true.  You need to set the elapsed event to call the method when the timer is fired. You also do not need to set Enabled and call Start() since since Start() just sets Enabled to True. For more info refer to the doc: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In order to call two methods with one event, have the event trigger a single callback and have that method invoke two other methods.

```
public void Pollback()
{
   Timer poller = new Timer(5000);
   poller.Elapsed = OnTimedEvent;
   poller.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e){
   GsmPhone_MessageReceived(source, e);
   secondMethod(source, e);
}
```